# How to render Url.Action with data in an Underscore.js template?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am trying to download a JSON file when we click on download button.

```
public ActionResult getJsonFile(Guid ProtocolId)
{
    List<Country> lst = new List<Country>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        lst.Add(new Country() { CountryId = i, CountryName = "India" + i });
    }
    string jsondata = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(lst);
    byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jsondata);
    return File(bytes, "application/json", "JsonData.json");
}
```

This code works fine for me, if I don't send any parameter (`ProtocolId`) to this method.

```
<script type="text/ng-template">
    <button type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("getJsonFile", "Home")">Download</button>
</script>
```

Here, the `protocolid` needs to be bound using these tags `<%= protocolid %>` (Underscore.js template) as I am using Backbone.js as client side script.

How can I bind the `protocolid` to the anchor tag so that when user clicks on `Download` link it should send the `protocolid` to the `getJsonFile()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the url returned by `@Url.Action("getJsonFile", "Home")` is of the following form `/home/json-file/` and that you're looking to get:

```
/home/json-file/1234
```

You could just append the id:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("getJsonFile", "Home")<%= protocolid %>">Download</a>
```

If the id is within the url, I think you can put an arbitrary string as the id in `Url.Action` *(not tested)*:

```
@Url.Action("getJsonFile", "Home", new { id = "<%=protocolid%>" })
```

So it generates the tags at the right place, e.g.:

```
/home/get-json/<%=protocolid%>/download/
```

So when rendered with underscore, the `<%=protocolid%>` is replaced correctly.

Comment: Hi Emile Bergeron, Thanks for solution. I have made few changes to 1st solution and it worked fine for me.                <a href="@Url.Action("getJsonFile", "Home")/protocolid=<%= protocolid %>">Download</a>